Does linux/drivers/hid/hid-roccat-lua.c control the lights of the mouse?
If you look linux/drivers/hid/hid-roccat-lua.c, it has a comment towards the beginning,
/*
 * Roccat Lua is a gamer mouse which cpi, button and light settings can be
 * configured.
 */

from which I'd expect that the code below has something to with the lights.
Where does it do so? Or, is there another *-roccat-* driver that does handle lights? I can't find one that does so, or at least I'm not able to recognize relevant pieces of code.
The word light only appears in that comment, and nowhere else in the file. Is it because in reality the driver is only about the "input" part of the mouse (the buttons) and not the output (the lights), so the comment is just informative about the mouse and not the driver?

The background is that I would like to learn writing a kernel-space driver for a keyboard with lights (I have a Roccat Vulcan Pro and a Roccat Vulcan 100), but so far I've only got lost between user-space drivers and books, without actually finding a solid resource that guides to practical implementation of a driver. So I followed somebody's suggestion of looking at existing modules.
Yeah, I am aware of modern user-space drivers, but I'm more interested in learning something about kernel-space drivers and kernel development in general.
